# Extracting metadata from IPFS URI in contract

Tags: nft, ipfs, meta-data

I have the IPFS URI that contains the metadata of an NFT. I need to access attributes from the metadata inside the smart contract. How would I go about doing that? I've tried using provable api 0.5 which doesn't seem to be working